# r - Is there a way to test if a number is either a radian or degree?

Tags: r, trigonometry, degrees, radians

I am in the process of adding tests to my R package `iemisc`. Previously, I created functions to use degrees rather than radians for trigonometric functions.

Is there a method to determine if a given number is in radians versus degrees?

If so, then I would like to incorporate that method in my tests.

For example, based off of the recent Win-Vector Blog article written by John Mount, http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2019/03/unit-tests-in-r/, and the `RUnit` vignette, I wrote the following test for cosd:

```
test_cosd <- function() {

library("iemisc")
RUnit::checkEquals(cosd(360), 1)
RUnit::checkEquals(cosd(90), 0)
RUnit::checkEquals(cosd(0), 1)
RUnit::checkException(cosd(pi * 3 / 4))
RUnit::checkException(cosd("sq"))

  invisible(NULL)
}
```

However, I would like to have a *checkException* for numbers that are radian measurements rather than degrees measurements.

Thank you.

Comment: In your particular case how would you differentiate radian and degree inputs if you were just looking at the input?

Comment: The answer to your question requires you to make some assumptions about the user domain.  Here's one simple approach:  "assume any number larger than 6.3 (a full circle) is degrees, otherwise ask user to specify".

Comment: @GGAnderson   Thank you for your suggestion, I will revise the function call to have the user specify degrees or radians.

Comment: @Dason   I asked the question because I don't know how to differentiate between radian and degree numbers. I was hoping that someone had a solution. Thank you.

Comment: @iembry I clarified the comment as an answer.  Would you accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to take advantage of the difference in magnitude between the measures to make reasonable inference about whether the input is degrees or radians.   A measurement in degrees is about 60 times the size of the same measurement in radians.  This can be seen from the underlying relationship:

```
180 degrees = pi (3.14159) radians
```

There is a simple heuristic possible, if you can safely assume users will use the tool only with angles smaller than a full circle (not unreasonable in many physical product engineering applications, unless corkscrew helices are involved).  In that case, it would be safe to assume values greater than 2*pi, or 6.28 represents degrees.

Otherwise, the values themselves are indistinguishable.